# Adding field to serializer with 2 foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models that look like this:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        topic = Topic.objects.filter(name=self.name)

        if topic:
            return topic[0].id

        super(Topic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.id

class PostTopic(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post= models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If the topic is already in the `Topic` table, then we return the id of that topic. We do not create another. When a user submits a `Post` with tagged topics (think of it as hashtags), then if those topics don't exist in the `Topic` table they will be created along with the relationship in `PostTopic`

That being said, here's how my serializer looks:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topics = serializers.ListField(
         child=serializers.CharField(max_length=256), max_length=3
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('user', 'status', 'topics')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        topics= validated_data.pop('topics')
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for topic in topics:
             topic_id = Topic(name=topic).save()
             PostTopic(post_id=post.id, topic_id=topic_id).save()

        return post
```

Currently, my serializer gives me an `AttributeError`, because topics is not a field in `Post`. How can I fix this so that I can make it work? If I use `PostTopic` then how would I get the user to give the actual topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [**`Many To Many`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship between `Post` and `Topic`. You can add it like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # rest of the fields
    topics = models.ManyToManyField('Topic', through='PostTopic')

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

   # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   #     **Important:** Django model's save function does not return anything. So handling it here won't be good. Let us handle duplicate entry in serializer
   #     topic = Topic.objects.filter(name=self.name)

   #     if topic:
   #         return topic[0].id

   #     super(Topic, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   #     return self.id

class PostTopic(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post= models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also, your method of handling duplicates won't work because model's save method does not return anything. Let us handle it in serializer with with some minor fixes:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topics = serializers.ListField(
         child=serializers.CharField(max_length=256), max_length=3
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('user', 'status', 'topics')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        topics= validated_data.pop('topics')
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for topic in topics:
             new_topic, _ = Topic.objects.get_or_create(name=topic)
             PostTopic(post_id=post.id, topic=new_topic).save()

        return post
```

Comment: Hmm, I like your solution, but I'm getting this error: `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: can you share your views?

Comment: Sure this is the only view I have for this serializer: `class CreateQuestionView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateQuestionSerializer`

Comment: I fixed it actually, `ListField` should have this added `write_only=True` and it fixes the error. Thank you so much for your help